# CBE Schematic and Wiring

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm in the process of installing a circuit breaker between a power supply and an HMI device, but have some uncertainty when it comes to illuminating the rocker switch.

The part number is TA35-C2F3FJ10C0. The schematic and datasheet are below:

[image]

[TA35 Rocker 1Pole Datasheet](https://my.mouser.com/datasheet/2/358/typ_TA35_Rocker_1Pole-1275974.pdf)

I'm using a 24 VDC line (as per the rating of the HMI) and have the circuit breaker tripping at the correct current (1A), but can't get the LED working. There's also a small threaded screw at the bottom of the switch (see picture below) that I'm not sure of the purpose. I was thinking it may adjust the internal resistance and help drive the LED depending on the supplied voltage or is simply a GND connection. In either case, any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Characters on the image below match the terminals as shown on the schematic above.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's to be wired as shown below.

[image]

It's probable that the screw is intended for adjusting the tripping current (factory set).

Comment: Hello vu2nan. Thank you for the response. I wired as your image depicts, but to no avail. I have 4 breakers of the same type on-hand and have tried with several of them, so don't believe a defective unit is to blame. The breaker certainly trips, but no LED. I tried with 240 VAC (per the rating on the datasheet), and the LED illuminates, just not with 24 VDC. Is there some internal circuitry that prevents the LED from working with DC?

Comment: Hi DepositionController, Part number TA35-C2F3FJ10C0 corresponds to SINGLE POLE, SUPPLY 240 V, RED TRANSPARENT ROCKER WITH '1' '0' EMBOSSED and CURRENT 1 A. The 240 V  indicator could be a neon bulb which will not illuminate at 24V. For your application the correct type would be TA35-C7F3FJ10C0.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, I was not able to locate that part # on any distributors in NA. I'll see if I can insert my own LED and resistor circuit.

Comment: Wish you good luck!